# Delegates and Datasource methods not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any possible way to call delegates and datasource inside a Grand Central Dispatch main_queue?

Please help. If these delegates and datasource aren't called, my images will not be displayed!

Here is the code:

```
messageWebService = [[MessageWebServices alloc]init];
    tempBO = [[MessageBO alloc]init];
    tempBO.messageId = self.messageID;
    dispatch_async(webServiceBackGroundQueue, ^(void){

        tempBO = [messageWebService getDetails:tempBO];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
         {

             if (!tempBO.isException)
             {
                 self.subjects.text = tempBO.subject;
                 self.content.text = tempBO.messageli;
                 self.userNmae.text = tempBO.userNmae;
                 self.creaDAte.text = tempBO.creationDate;
                 self.phoneNumb.text = tempBO.phoneNumber;
                 self.eMail.text = tempBO.email;
                 self.amount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@",tempBO.priceAmount];
                 self.imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempBO.imageURL]];
                 self.img = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
                 if(self.img)
                 {
                     [imageArray addObject:self.img];
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_photo.png"]];
                 }
                 hFlowView.delegate = self;
                 hFlowView.dataSource = self;
                 hFlowView.pageControl = hPageControl;


             }



        });
    });
```

Comment: can you explain in more detail?? its hope possible....

Comment: why you need to call it inside GCD?

Comment: I'm using a third party library called pagedFlowView.. The image view is inside that and it has its own delegate and datasource methods. IF these methods aren't called, The imageView is always blank. All the images are received from web services.

Comment: The rule for bugs: Bugs are caused by mistakes you make. The first step to finding a bug is to get rid of the idea in your mind that something is not working for some magical reason. First realise that you did something wrong. Then ask yourself the question: What did I do wrong?

Comment: In this case, looks like there is some code that you haven't written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly call the delegate / datasource method, but you can call the supporting methods which will trigger the delegate or data source methods.
For eg. For table view - if you call reload table view, the data source and the delegate methods which are associated to reload the table will be called.

But in case of GCD, only if the respective class's object is in the scope, they will reflect the change. Or else it will be of no use.

Please provide extra details of your exact scenario / code so the we can guid you more accurately.

Comment: Thanks. I went through the code in the third party library and found a [reloadData] call. Now everything works. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put any code in a gcd block. However, be careful that the object, the delegate object and the data source object are still in scope when the block is executed. You may need to move a local variable (for example) to be a member variable.